# Dynamically Changing Distribution in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, agent, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am using AnyLogic to develop a model. 
I used the 'distribution' element to initialize values for a parameter in my model. It is working fine, but I want to update these values as my simulation proceeds forward. e.g. if in week 1, the distribution can have values:

[Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VbxI.jpg)

But in week 2, I wan to update these values, then again in each coming week.

I have some equation based on which I want to make calculations and update these values.
I could not find any functionality in AnyLogic concerning this.
Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create distribution from scratch, using [various constructors](http://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/javadoc/com/anylogic/engine/CustomDistribution.html?resultof=%22custom%22%20%22distribution%22%20%22distribut%22%20). Pass into constructor array with existing and additional values to get the updated custom distribution. Your distribution is created with this constructor:

`CustomDistribution(double[] intervalStarts, int[] numberOfObservations, Agent owner)`

It may be convenient to store initial array in database, and each next array in model variable.